# UNO platform Skia+GTK doesn't start

Tags: c#, xaml, gtk, uno-platform

I've an app made with uno platform, that works without problems when building for UWP.

But when building for Skia+GTK and running it on Windows it shows the following in the console log.

```
fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.AddDeleteThemeTransition[0]
      The member AddDeleteThemeTransition.AddDeleteThemeTransition() is not implemented in Uno.
fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ContentThemeTransition[0]
      The member ContentThemeTransition.ContentThemeTransition() is not implemented in Uno.
fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ReorderThemeTransition[0]
      The member ReorderThemeTransition.ReorderThemeTransition() is not implemented in Uno.
fail: Uno.UI.DataBinding.BindingPropertyHelper[0]
      The [ScrollViewer] property getter does not exist on type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewList]
fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.BrushTransition[0]
      The member BrushTransition.BrushTransition() is not implemented in Uno.
fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.BrushTransition[0]
      The member TimeSpan BrushTransition.Duration is not implemented in Uno.
fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentPresenter[0]
      The member BrushTransition ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition is not implemented in Uno.
```

Also getting elements with `this.FindName()` just returns `null`.

I tried running `uno-check`, but it showed no problems.